# Why does a select query require an IX lock?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2, deadlock

While inspecting the deadlock graph below, I found that a `SELECT` query (only query inside the SP being executed by the first process `process569f048`) and an `UPDATE` query forming a deadlock; and the `SELECT` query is requiring an `IX` lock.

In what situation such locks are necessary for a `SELECT`? What can I do to avoid the deadlock?

Here is the `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT TOP (@p_takeCount)
     t.Id
    ,s.Column2
    ,t.STATUS
    ,t.Column3
    ,t.Column4
FROM Table2 t WITH (INDEX (IX_Table2))
INNER JOIN Table1 s ON s.Id = t.ParentId
WHERE t.STATUS != 0
    AND t.Column5 IS NULL
    AND s.SomeId = @p_someId
    AND s.Category = 2
ORDER BY t.id
```

Here is the plan:

[image]

Here is the `UPDATE` query:

```
update Table2
set [Status] = @0, Column5 = null, Column6 = @1
where ([Id] = @2)
```

Here is the plan:

[image]

Here is the deadlock graph:

```
<deadlock>
  <victim-list>
    <victimProcess id="process569f048" />
  </victim-list>
  <process-list>
    <process id="process569f048" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="PAGE: 5:1:3017144" waittime="2867" ownerId="964271246" transactionname="SELECT" lasttranstarted="2017-01-29T10:10:49.643" XDES="0x800f9d20" lockMode="S" schedulerid="10" kpid="10108" status="suspended" spid="70" sbid="2" ecid="2" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2017-01-29T10:10:49.643" lastbatchcompleted="2017-01-29T10:10:49.643" clientapp="EntityFramework" hostname="LOCALHOST" hostpid="4936" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="964271246" currentdb="5" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="" line="17" stmtstart="1298" stmtend="1954" sqlhandle="0x03000500d21f5e3dd6d19700cca400000100000000000000" />
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf />
    </process>
    <process id="process8ee3dc8" taskpriority="0" logused="17956" waitresource="PAGE: 5:1:3017343" waittime="2864" ownerId="964271345" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2017-01-29T10:10:49.667" XDES="0xafdbb03b0" lockMode="IX" schedulerid="17" kpid="9468" status="suspended" spid="61" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2017-01-29T10:10:49.703" lastbatchcompleted="2017-01-29T10:10:49.703" clientapp="EntityFramework" hostname="LOCALHOST" hostpid="20696" loginname="dbuser_d" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="964271345" currentdb="5" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="" line="1" stmtstart="74" sqlhandle="0x02000000403aaa03bd8879de1c73d49641f1f81b6ca095af" />
        <frame procname="" line="1" sqlhandle="0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" />
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
        (@0 tinyint,@1 varchar(64),@2 bigint)update [dbo].[Table2]
        set [Status] = @0, [Column5] = null, [Column6] = @1
        where ([Id] = @2)
      </inputbuf>
    </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
    <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="3017144" dbid="5" objectname="" id="lockc296c6380" mode="IX" associatedObjectId="72057594073317376">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process8ee3dc8" mode="IX" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process569f048" mode="S" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </pagelock>
    <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="3017343" dbid="5" objectname="" id="lockd33965a80" mode="S" associatedObjectId="72057594073317376">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process569f048" mode="S" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process8ee3dc8" mode="IX" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </pagelock>
  </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

Index details:

```
[PK_Table2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC);
[IX_Table2]([Column5] ASC, [Status] ASC) INCLUDE ( [Id],[ParentId],[Column3],[Column4]) WHERE ([Column5] IS NULL);
```

Object with id `72057594073317376` (`associatedObjectId`) is: `[IX_Table2]`

Comment: Index hints, really? What other "customizations" are you using? How are the indices on the table defined?

Comment: The select takes the `TOP x` from a table filtering for the status, while the update is updating the status...

Comment: [This question and answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/87688/7257)  are about a similar problem, but in this case it looks like the same thing is happening with no lookup (so actually the linked answer may be no help at all). I have voted to migrate to dba.stackexchange, I think you are more likely to get an accurate answer there.

Comment: @Shnugo I understand that. But should not that just _block_ a transaction? Why the deadlock?

Comment: @GarethD I am considering to post it there, thanks!

Comment: This is also similar http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62947/deadlock-when-update-different-rows-with-non-clustered-index - and I think holds the key, even though the `SELECT` only uses the non clustered index, it still takes a lock on the clustered index to prevent updates to the clustering key. Is the associated object_id 72057594073317376 the object_id for the clustered, or nonclustered index?

Comment: @GarethD I tried `OBJECT_NAME(72057594073317376 )` to get the object name, but it throws error: `Arithmetic overflow`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797023/how-to-figure-out-what-object-is-represented-by-associatedobjectid-during-blocki @mshsayem

Comment: Please show details of the clustered index and non clustered index definitions

Comment: @SteveFord Details are added at the bottom of the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locks are always necessary for selects, as long as you're not using dirty reads.

The update query changes the index. Would you really want the select query not to even *notice* the index changed? You'd just get random nonsense from your queries once in a while (in fact, exactly in the scenario you have here - instead of a deadlock, you'd get malformed data).

Of course, a select doesn't usually take an exclusive lock - and even in this case, you can see that the lock is shared, not exclusive. But that still means that anyone who wants to *write* to that data, can't. And the update statement needs to do exactly that - while at the same time holding an exclusive lock on the index, which the select needs to complete.

Deadlocks cannot be avoided *in general*. They're an expected behaviour you should be prepared for - the typical response in your application should be to repeat the transaction when you get the 1205 error. This is a compromise between performance and convenience, without jeopardising correctness. The process that gets the error is chosen at random, so you need this on both the reads and writes.

<strike>In your case, it's obvious that you're changing the clustered index - that's usually a bad idea, and leads to plenty of deadlock opportunities (after all, you're *rebuilding the table*, at least partially). Consider changing your indices to be more in line with what reads and write your application is actually doing. If it happens often, it will also likely be bad for performance.</strike>

EDIT: Actually, it seems that the locks are on two pages of `IX_Table2` - the one where the key used to be, and the one where it needs to be after the change. The two locks are taken in a sequence, and in a different order from the select. Given the layout of the index, this is going to happen relatively often - since both statements deal with `Column5` that is null. I don't think it's really avoidable in this case - maybe you could tweak the index layout a bit, but that really only makes sense if the deadlocks pose actual problems - if you only lose a few seconds every day or less, it's likely wasted effort and with likely negative side-effects.

For more information about analysing and solving deadlocks on MS SQL, try [How to resolve a deadlock](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/832524/sql-server-technical-bulletin---how-to-resolve-a-deadlock). If you need more info to solve your problem, consult with your DBA, and consider posting a question on DBA Stack Exchange - make sure to include all the necessary information, including at least the DDL for the table involved, including the indices. Use `sp_help` to translate the object ids in the deadlock report to the actual names in your DDL.

Comment: You are mistaking a clustered index with a clustering key, altering a clustering key is generally bad, but it is literally impossible to update a table (that is not a heap) without updating the clustered index. Furthermore, the Select statement never actually touches the clustered index on table2, so in theory, the update statement should update the clustered index on table2, then get blocked by the select, then when the select is finished it should finish updating the nonclustered index.

Comment: The application reads and modifies the status fields of some rows (<1% of 30M+ rows) of `Table2` frequently (consider multiple process changing a _status_ column). How can I avoid clustered index changing? (The clustered index key column is just an auto-increment bigint).

Comment: @GarethD Exactly! That's my question. Here, `SELECT` and `UPDATE` should block one, but why the deadlock?

Comment: @mshsayem The way most deadlocks form - the two queries acquire the locks on the two resources in a different order. A locks X and requests Y, while at the same time B locks Y and requests X. You'll really need to add the definitions of your table and indices if you want more detailed help. And any triggers that might be involved, of course. Answer the questions in my answer :)

Comment: @GarethD The select could only avoid touching the clustered index on Table2 if IX_Table2 includes all the columns being requested by the query. Most likely, the query tries to lookup by `IX_Table2`, and when it needs the remaining columns, it needs a lock on the clustered index - which already has an exclusive lock that is now trying to acquire another exclusive lock on `IX_Table2`, but can't. Or vice versa. It's hard to tell unless mshsayem actually shows us the names of the objects being locked :)

Comment: @Luaan But the plan for the `SELECT` shows otherwise. It does not touch the clustered index of the `Table2`: `PK_Table2` as `IX_Table2` includes all necessary columns required for the `SELECT`. It do touch the clustered index of the `Table1` though, but the `UPDATE` query has nothing to do with `Table1`.

Comment: The plan for select shows that it does use PK - take another look on your plan.

Comment: @mshsayem You still haven't included the required information, so wild guesses are the best you can get :) All I can see is that you're sorting and filtering by the `id`, but we don't see how the indices are built, and we still don't know which objects are actually being locked. So the best I can tell you at this point is "make your application resistant to deadlock errors". Deadlocks aren't necessarily a bad thing, or avoidable - they're not generally considered an error, they just require you to retry the operation.

Comment: @mshsayem please note that where a table has a clustered index all non-clustered indexes have the clustering key as part of the index and will therefore need to be updated in the case of an update to the clustering key.

Comment: @IvanStarostin It uses the PK of `Table1` which is not a problem as the `UPDATE` has nothing to do with `Table1`. The `SELECT` does not touch PK of `Table2` as the index `IX_Table2` has all necessary information (note there is no _Key Look Up_ in the plan.

Comment: @Luaan Sorry, my work hour was up (GMT+6). Index definitions updated (please see at the bottom of the post). Thanks for your help!

Comment: @mshsayem Added more info. It's a typical mostly unavoidable deadlock -  the index update must be "atomic" and causes a change in two pages, requiring two separate locks. The query *also* needs multiple locks, since it needs to order the rows, effectively spanning the whole filter range - and the ordering mustn't change in the middle of the query.

Comment: The edit explains a lot! Thanks! Now can you explain if I omit `Column5=null` in the `UPDATE` query (the field has default value `null`), can the deadlock be avoided? (It's true that the deadlock only happens less than 5 times in a day; not a big deal; still, just being curious)

Comment: @mshsayem It might help, but I wouldn't bet on it. How often do you do the update? Would it make sense to take a table lock for the updates? That would avoid taking two separate locks, which means no deadlocks and also a somewhat faster update. If you query far more often than update, it shouldn't be noticeable for the readers. Are there many concurrent reads and/or writes?

Comment: There are a 40+ readers polling at regular intervals and 45+ writers. Mostly all of those deal with only <0.05% of `Table2`. I will observe what happens if `Column5` update is omitted. Anyway, thanks a lot! It was a great help!

Comment: @mshsayem Yeah, that's exactly where you'd expect a deadlock once in a while - I'd say hardening your application against the deadlock errors is most likely the best approach here.

Answer (score 3):

If you look closely in the graph you can see:

The reader, process: process569f048 has a Shared lock on page: 3017343 and is waiting on a shared lock on page: 3017144 of Object 72057594073317376

The Update process: process8ee3dc8 has an IX lock on page: 3017144 and is waiting on an IX lock on 3017343 of Object 72057594073317376.

This is where the deadlock is.

To find the object referred to you can use the info below gleaned from [stack overflow answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354035/sql-server-deadlock-object-ids-are-too-large)
The object id refers to hobts (Heap Or Binary Tree), found in sys.partitions.

Try the following query inside database 5, and you will find which object and which index is affected.

```
SELECT hobt_id, object_name(p.[object_id]), index_id 
FROM sys.partitions p 
WHERE hobt_id = 72057594073317376
```

As I noted in my comment that where a table has a clustered index all non-clustered indexes have the clustering key as part of the index and will therefore need to be updated in the case of an update to the clustering key.
I suspect that this object will be the secondary index which needs to be updated by the update, perhaps because it is the last page.

Comment: I don't see any problems with this answer, but wanted to give the TL;DR version. The assertion "the `SELECT` query is requiring an IX lock" from the question is false.

Comment: Thanks! I ran the query you mentioned but it returns nothing for the object `72057594073317376`

Comment: Hmm. Got the id from a fresh deadlock graph, and I found the object to be `[Table2].[IX_Table2]` as expected.

Comment: I think you are trying to mean this: _(probably) The last few pages of `IX_Table2` is being accessed by both queries; they required page lock, and while the `SELECT` was trying to lock some, the `UPDATE` were locking others until the moment each required the rest pages which were already locked by the other_.

Comment: @BenThul Thanks! I understand it now. I interpreted the `waiter-list` and `owner-list` wrong. The deadlock is actually happening due to incompatible PAGE locks held by the queries.

Comment: Now another question: Why does the `UPDATE` need 2 pages of `[IX_Table2]`; it is just updating a single entry. Has the entry spanned 2 pages of `IX_Table2`? Last block of one page and first block of another page? Is that possible?

Comment: It could be a leaf page and a non-leaf page. You can do some `dbcc page` voodoo to verify.

Comment: @mshsayem It's changing the keys of the index. Obviously that means it needs to move the item from one place in the index to another - which is quite likely to require changes to two pages, the one where it used to be, and the one where it will be. That operation must be atomic, so that a query doesn't see the same item twice (or misses it entirely). That requires two locks.

Answer (score 0):

It was my wrong interpretation of the deadlock graph. The `wait-resource` fields clearly indicates that:

- `SELECT` process is holding an `S` lock on a *PAGE* of `IX_Table2`: 3017343
- `UPDATE` process is holding an `IX` lock on a *PAGE* of `IX_Table2`: 
  3017144
- `SELECT` needs the page 3017144 with `S` lock; but it is held by the `UPDATE`
- `UPDATE` needs the page 3017343 with `IX` lock; but it is held by the `SELECT`
- `IX` and `S` modes are not compatible. So, DEADLOCK.
- And, `SELECT` is not asking for an `IX` lock

Fix (for now):

- Re-run the `SELECT`
- [Use retries in the SP](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175791(v=sql.80).aspx) containing the `SELECT`
- `SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY LOW;` in the SP